# Fixed Position Social Links Cause Text Links to Become Unclickable

Tags: html, css

On the left side of my site, I have a vertical column of social sharing icons that are fixed to always remain in sight when the user scrolls the page.  Whenever the user scrolls the page so that the social sharing icons are directly lined up horizontally with any regular text links in the body of the page, those text links become unclickable.  If the user scrolls up or down slightly so that the social links are no longer directly adjacent to the text links, the text links once again become clickable.  What is causing this?

```css
.facebook {
  background-color: #531458;
}

.twitter {
  background-color: #531458;
}

.sendemail {
  background-color: #531458;
}

.share {
  background-color: #531458;
}

.socialfloat {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 85vh;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
}

.socialfloat .fbtn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="socialfloat">
  <a class="fbtn share twitter" title="Twitter" href="javascript:popup('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Some text.')"><img src="https://website/images/twitter_small.png"></a>
  <a class="fbtn share facebook" title="Facebook" href="javascript:popup('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://website.com')"><img src="https://website.com/images/facebook_small.png"></a>
  <a class="fbtn share sendemail" title="E-mail" href="mailto:?subject=Some text."><img src="https://website.com/images/envelope_small.png"></a>
  <a class="fbtn share share" title="Share" href="javascript:copyToClipboard()"><img src="https://website/images/share_small.png"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing `width: 100%;` from `.socialfloat` solved my problem.